# How to display the DateTimeField stored in IST in db in IST itself given the condition that USE_TZ=True?

Tags: python, django, timezone

So, I am a novice in Django and have set my timezone as 'Asia/Kolkata' and USE_TZ=True in the settings file. For the datetime that is stored in UTC in the database, the display is in my current timezone. However, for the datetime that is stored in IST in the db, the admin is adding +5:30 for display(i.e. it assumes the values in db are in UTC)

I want to find a way to manually tell those models/admin that USE_TZ=False for them.

I tried extending the DateTimeField and overriding the function get_internal_type to return CharField and not DateTime. It is working fine as well. However, I do not understand how it actually is working in the background.

```
class MyDateTimeField(DateTimeField):
    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "CharField"

class FileUpload(models.Model):
    ....
    ....
    created_at = models.MyDateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.MyDateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Also, for the long run, I am a bit wary about the model level changes and want to know if anything else can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

from datetime import datetime

current_time=datetime.now()

created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=current_time.strftime("%G-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), blank=True)

or

created_at = models.CharField(default=current_time.strftime("%G-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), blank=True)

If you dont want to provide default time then simply give default='' for CharField.For formatting datetime value i have used strftime.